# How to fix "NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated" while uploading Objects in IBM Cloud

Tags: go, cloud, ibm-cloud, bucket, object-storage

I am using the below Go lang code:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-go/aws/credentials/ibmiam"
    "github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
)



var (
    apiKey            = os.Getenv("MY_COS_IBM_KEY_TEMP")
    serviceInstanceID = os.Getenv("MY_SVC_IBM_INST_ID_TEMP")
    authEndpoint      = "https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token"
    serviceEndpoint   = "https://s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud"
)

func main() {

    oldBucket := "pixmedia"
    newBucket := "mediaflixibm"
    newColdBucket := "newmediaflixibmx"

    conf := aws.NewConfig().
        WithEndpoint(serviceEndpoint).
        WithCredentials(ibmiam.NewStaticCredentials(aws.NewConfig(),
            authEndpoint, apiKey, serviceInstanceID)).
        WithS3ForcePathStyle(true)

    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())
    client := s3.New(sess, conf)

    input := &s3.CreateBucketInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(newBucket),
    }
    client.CreateBucket(input)

    input2 := &s3.CreateBucketInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(newColdBucket),
        CreateBucketConfiguration: &s3.CreateBucketConfiguration{
            LocationConstraint: aws.String("us-geo"),
        },
    }
    output, err := client.CreateBucket(input2)
    fmt.Println(output)
    fmt.Println(err)

    d, err := client.ListBuckets(&s3.ListBucketsInput{})
    fmt.Println(d)
    fmt.Println(err)

    //TO do
    // Upload , Download, Display files

    file, err := os.Open("/Users/kumargaurav/Downloads/test.png")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err opening file: %s", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    fileInfo, _ := file.Stat()
    size := fileInfo.Size()
    buffer := make([]byte, size) // read file content to buffer

    file.Read(buffer)
    fileBytes := bytes.NewReader(buffer)
    _ = http.DetectContentType(buffer)
    var key = "ob-xx"
    upParams := &s3manager.UploadInput{
        ACL:                     new(string),
        Body:                    fileBytes,
        Bucket:                  &oldBucket,
        CacheControl:            new(string),
        ContentDisposition:      new(string),
        ContentEncoding:         new(string),
        ContentLanguage:         new(string),
        ContentMD5:              new(string),
        ContentType:             new(string),
        Expires:                 &time.Time{},
        GrantFullControl:        new(string),
        GrantRead:               new(string),
        GrantReadACP:            new(string),
        GrantWriteACP:           new(string),
        Key:                     &key,
        Metadata:                map[string]*string{},
        RequestPayer:            new(string),
        RetentionExpirationDate: &time.Time{},
        RetentionLegalHoldId:    new(string),
        RetentionPeriod:         new(int64),
        SSECustomerAlgorithm:    new(string),
        SSECustomerKey:          new(string),
        SSECustomerKeyMD5:       new(string),
        SSEKMSKeyId:             new(string),
        ServerSideEncryption:    new(string),
        StorageClass:            new(string),
        Tagging:                 new(string),
        WebsiteRedirectLocation: new(string),
    }

    //sess = session.Must(session.NewSession())

    // Create an uploader with the session and default options

    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)

    res, err := uploader.Upload(upParams)

    fmt.Println("Res is", res)
    fmt.Println("Error is ", err)

    sess1 := session.Must(session.NewSession())

    uploader1 := s3manager.NewUploader(sess1, func(u *s3manager.Uploader) {
        // Define a strategy that will buffer 25 MiB in memory
        u.BufferProvider = s3manager.NewBufferedReadSeekerWriteToPool(25 * 1024 * 1024)
    })

    ures, err := uploader1.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("pixmedia"),
        Key:    aws.String("ob-xx"),
        Body:   bytes.NewReader(buffer),
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println("URes is", ures)

    fmt.Println("Uerr is", err)

    
}
```

I am trying to upload object after creating the bucket, bucket creation is successful but i am getting below error while uploading objects to cos bucket:

Uerr is NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors

Error is coming from:

fmt.Println("Uerr is", err) - This line is printing the error and this is because of     ures, err := uploader1.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{

Please help.

To run this main.go file put in the root folder of : https://github.com/IBM/ibm-cos-sdk-go

Comment: Which line is throwing that error? Provide more details. Have you tried to simplify the code?

Comment: fmt.Println("Uerr is", err) - This line is printing the error and this is because of     ures, err := uploader1.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{

Comment: in the aws sdk, that message means no credentials were found in any of the methods the sdk tried.  I'm guessing it's the same in your case, since this appears to be an aws compatibility layer for the ibm cloud.